# "restart" vs "reset" in the context of a game or puzzle

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Given a partially-completed puzzle or game (e.g. sudoku or klondike solitaire), would reverting the puzzle/game to the initial state be considered "restarting", "resetting", or is there a third, better word? Thank you!

Comment: They mean what the game designer thinks they mean.

Comment: The terms make more sense for physical games: 'restarts' are associated with games where competitors return to the start without moving the props or changing the landscape (e.g. 100m race) whereas 'resets' are associated with games where competitors don't change location but do put the pieces back (e.g. chess). Use whichever analogy better fits your puzzle or game.

Answer (score 1):

Reset seems to make more sense here, in the context that board games or puzzles may be "set" initially, so to "reset" would be to call back to the original setting.

"Restart" would more literally refer to a process, in as much as a game or puzzle is a process. However, since you could halt or suspend a game, leave it in it's current state, then come back and resume it from where you stopped, you would be "restarting" the game/puzzle process.

Answer (score 0):

In general, 'reset' means just zeroing results, possibly without starting game again (game may go to pause state after resetting).
'Restart', in contrast, means start from the beginning, possibly without zeroing results (in some games you can save all your game achievements in this case, and only move to some start point in game space) or just start after pause.
So, the best choice depends on the rules of the game (and, of course, the peculiarities of its implementation).